# iTextSharp hides text when write

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

All

I am inserting text in existing PDF file using iTextSharp Library, some times if any image in the position where i writing text in PDF page, it keep hides the written text, how to write text on the existing image.

```
    Dim iNumOfPages As Integer = 0, iFile As Integer = 0, iRotation As Integer
    Dim objPdfReader As PdfReader
    Dim objDoc As Document = Nothing
    Dim objPdfWriter As PdfWriter = Nothing
    Dim objContentByte As PdfContentByte
    Dim objPage As PdfImportedPage
    Dim objFileStream As FileStream = Nothing

    objFileStream = New FileStream(sDestFile, FileMode.Create)
        objPdfReader = New PdfReader(slSourceFiles.Item(iFile))
        iNumOfPages = objPdfReader.NumberOfPages
        objDoc = New Document(objPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
        objPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(objDoc, objFileStream)
        objDoc.Open()
        objContentByte = objPdfWriter.DirectContent

        Dim objTempCB As PdfContentByte = objPdfWriter.DirectContent
        objPDFStamper = New PdfStamper(objPdfReader, objFileStream)

    While i < iNumOfPages
                i = i + 1
                objDoc.SetPageSize(objPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                objDoc.NewPage()
                objPage = objPdfWriter.GetImportedPage(objPdfReader, i)
                iRotation = objPdfReader.GetPageRotation(i)


                    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,     BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
                        Dim bc As BaseColor = BaseColor.BLUE


                        objContentByte.BeginText()
                        objContentByte.SetTextMatrix(400, 765) 'objContentByte.SetTextMatrix(400, 765)
                        objContentByte.SetFontAndSize(bf, 9)
                        objContentByte.SetColorFill(bc)
                        objContentByte.ShowText("Mytext................")
                        objContentByte.EndText()

        If (iRotation = 90 Or iRotation = 270) Then
                        objContentByte.AddTemplate(objPage, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, objPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
                    Else
                        objContentByte.AddTemplate(objPage, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
                    End If
    End While
```

Any one help to write text above to existing images...

Thanks,
Senthil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the lines

```
   objContentByte.AddTemplate(objPage, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, objPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
```

and

```
   objContentByte.AddTemplate(objPage, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
```

can you try to write to the DirectContentUnder from the PdfWriter:

```
    objContentByte = objPdfWriter.DirectContent
    Dim objContentByteUnder as PdfContentByte  = objPdfWriter.DirectContentUnder
             .....
             objContentByte.BeginText()
             .....
             objContentByteUnder.AddTemplate(objPage, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, objPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
             objContentByteUnder.AddTemplate(objPage, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i tried with objContentByte = objPdfWriter.DirectContentUnder, and it still keeps hide text if image appeared.

Comment: You have to write the text to the objPdfWriter.DirectContent and the image to the objPdfWriter.DirectContentUnder

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i am getting it works, by replacing the objContentByte.BeginText() ............. objContentByte.EndText() code to next to 'End If' statement..

Comment: Hi Snethil, I am getting same problem, will you please tell me where should exactly BeginText and EndText be called?

Comment: @Supereme: you do have the DirectContent and the DirectContentUnder, if you add the text to the DirectContent and the image to the DirectContentUnder. The text should appear ontop of the image.

Comment: Thanks peer, it worked when I used DirectContent for writing my text to PDF and other contents were written using DirectContentUnder. But along with that I also had to use SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL) of PdfContentByte which helped me to appear my text above the image/background of the pdf being written on.